# Getting the list of mapped label encodings in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn

I have label encoded my dataset which contains about 100+ distinct strings.

So, is there any way I can get a list of the labels along-side the original strings.

Like example:

```
apple  --> 3
orange --> 4
pear   --> 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html):

> **classes_**: array of shape (n_class,)
>       Holds the label for each class.

Building a `dict` from this should be trivial.

As a rule of thumb, an sklearn stage typically keeps this type of information in some member ending with an underscore (e.g., `classes_` in this case).

**Example**

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
>>> preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit(['apply', 'banana']).classes_
array(['apply', 'banana'], 
      dtype='|S6')
```

Comment: So, if this is the code used for encoding: `labeled_df = String_df.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)`

But, doing `print(labeled_df.classes_)` returns an error which says: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'classes_'`.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Dawny33 Added an example

Comment: BTW, your example is indeed wrong. You should be querying the *stage* for `classes_`, not the transformation output. In your case, you're using a temporary stage object (`LabelEncoder()`), so you don't have any object to query.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thank you :)  But still, I don't get the mapping between the actual labels and the encoded labels, right?

Comment: @Dawny33 The encoded labels are ordinal integers, and the labels in `classes_` appear with this order. So if `banana` is in position 1, then `banana` was encoded to 1.

Comment: Did. Thanks for the help :)